# Why didSet does not change variables in a custom Struct?

Tags: swift

I have an **enum** called: `AnimationKind` I am using this enum as input of my custom Struct called: `AnimationPhase`, how ever for unknown reason for me, I cannot update my `AnimationPhase` variable with didSet of Struct `AnimationKind`, why it does not work?

```
enum AnimationKind { case long, short, none }
```

---

```
struct AnimationPhase {

    var animationKind: AnimationKind {

        didSet(newValue) {

            switch newValue {
            case .long:
                self.withAnimation = true
                self.durationOfAnimation = 2.0
            case .short:
                self.withAnimation = true
                self.durationOfAnimation = 0.5
            case .none:
                self.withAnimation = false
                self.durationOfAnimation = 0.0
            }

 
        }
        
    }
    private(set) var withAnimation: Bool
    private(set) var durationOfAnimation: Double

    init(animationKind: AnimationKind) {

        self.animationKind = animationKind

        switch animationKind {
        case .long:
            self.withAnimation = true
            self.durationOfAnimation = 2.0
        case .short:
            self.withAnimation = true
            self.durationOfAnimation = 0.5
        case .none:
            self.withAnimation = false
            self.durationOfAnimation = 0.0
        }
 
    }

}
```

---

**use case:**

```
var test: AnimationPhase = AnimationPhase(animationKind: .long)

print(test.animationKind, test.withAnimation, test.durationOfAnimation)

test.animationKind = .none

print(test.animationKind, test.withAnimation, test.durationOfAnimation)
```

---

**It prints:**

long true 2.0

none true 2.0

**Which it should be:**

long true 2.0

none false 0.0

Answer (score 4):

You can *name* the `didSet` variable `newValue` but that's just a name. It is in fact the *old* value. (By default, its name is `oldValue`. You are just changing that name to `newValue` but that doesn't magically turn it into the new value, any more than naming my Honda "BMW" turns it into an actual BMW.)

To get the new value, just look right at the property. Change

```
    didSet(newValue) {
        switch newValue {
```

To

```
    didSet {
        switch animationKind {
```

Comment: And see my book, http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_setter_observers, to  know how setter observers work / behave.

Comment: I do not wanted change the oldValue to newValue by naming it! I thought the newValue is coming value to set! just my mistake because I was thinking about getter and setter way. I would say typo from me.

Comment: Good answer, but I assure you that when I put a Tesla sticker on a hooptie, it causes all protons and neutrons to be filtered out of gasoline upon entry.

Comment: @user It's much more than a typo. As I said in my first comment, you have to know how `willSet` and `didSet` actually work; you cannot make them work a different way by wishing or imagining. — On the other hand, one might argue that this shows the danger of being able to rename the incoming value. If you had not written `didSet(newValue)` but had just written `didSet`, you would have discovered that there was _no_ `newValue` coming in. Instead, you put a piece of black tape over the red flashing light.

Comment: by default most of the closures in Swift and SwiftUI gave the `newValue` I can say maybe 95% and since most of us like me mostly using didSet then I assumed it must be given newValue, but I did not think about it twice, the reason I asked the question was, because I thought I must use a mutating function instead of didSet.

Comment: That is a separate question. :) `didSet` is assumed to be potentially mutating - and you can see why. It depends on the setting of a property, which is _itself_ a mutation. Thus there is no need to say `mutating` here, because if we were not mutating we would not even _be_ here.